# ¿Cómo comparar por medio de un if con equals con variable que están fuera de la función?

Tags: java

tengo una duda, tengo unos String fuera de una funcion de un boton, y quiero colocar un if dentro de la funcion del boton pero al intentar compararla con un String que esta fuera de la funcion no me aparece.

```
    private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    conexion objConexion = new conexion();
    personasBL oPersonas = recuperarDatosGui();
    String strSentenciaInsert = String.format("INSERT INTO inscritos (ID,fecha,ciudad,programa,JorDiurna,JorNocturna,primerApell,segundoApell,nombres,fechaNaci,lugarNacimi,eps,ars,cualAseguradora,nivelSisben,otroSisben,docuCC,docuTi,docuOtro,NumDocume,Expedida,generoM,generoF,edad,tipoSangre,estadoCivilSoltero,estadoCivilCasada,estadoCivilUnionL,estadoCivilOtro,ocupacion,correoElec,direccionReside,telefono,barrio,estrato,entidadTrabaja,cargo,fechaIngresoEm,direccionEmpre,telefonoEmpre,nombreAcudiente,cedulaAcudiente,fechaNaciAcudiente,telefonoAcudiente,parentesco,profesionAcudiente,secundariaInstitu,secundariaCiudad,secundariaTitulo,secundariaAno,tecnicoInstitucion,tecnicoCiudad,tecnicoTitulo,tecnicoAno,univeInstitucion,univeCiudad,univeTitulo,univeAno,CulturaIndigena,culturaAfro,culturaReinser,culturaRoom,culturaCabezaF,culturaFrontera,culturaDezpla,pagoCredito,pagoContado) "
        + "VALUES (null, '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s', '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",oPersonas.getFecha(),oPersonas.getCiudad(),oPersonas.getPrograma(),oPersonas.getJorDiurna(),oPersonas.getJorNocturna(),oPersonas.getPrimerApell(),oPersonas.getSegundoApell(),oPersonas.getNombres(),oPersonas.getFechaNaci(),oPersonas.getLugarNacimi(),oPersonas.getEps(),oPersonas.getArs(),oPersonas.getCualAseguradora(),oPersonas.getNivelSisben(),oPersonas.getOtroSisben(),oPersonas.getDocuCC(),oPersonas.getDocuTi(),oPersonas.getDocuOtro(),oPersonas.getNumDocume(),oPersonas.getExpedida(),oPersonas.getGeneroM(),oPersonas.getGeneroF(),oPersonas.getEdad(),oPersonas.getTipoSangre(),oPersonas.getEstadoCivilSoltero(),oPersonas.getEstadiCivilCasada(),oPersonas.getEstadoCivilUnionL(),oPersonas.getEstadoCivilOtro(),oPersonas.getOcupacion(),oPersonas.getCorreoElec(),oPersonas.getDireccionReside(),oPersonas.getTelefono(),oPersonas.getBarrio(),oPersonas.getEstrato(),oPersonas.getEntidadTrabaja(),oPersonas.getCargo(),oPersonas.getFechaIngresoEm(),oPersonas.getDireccionEmpre(),oPersonas.getTelefonoEmpre(),oPersonas.getNombreAcudiente(),oPersonas.getCedulaAcudiente(),oPersonas.getFechaNaciAcudiente(),oPersonas.getTelefonoAcudiente(),oPersonas.getParentesco(),oPersonas.getProfesionAcudiente(),oPersonas.getSecundariaInstitu(),oPersonas.getSecundariaCiudad(),oPersonas.getSecundariaTitulo(),oPersonas.getSecundariaAno(),oPersonas.getTecnicoInstitucion(),oPersonas.getTecnicoCiudad(),oPersonas.getTecnicoTitulo(),oPersonas.getTecnicoAño(),oPersonas.getUniveInstitucion(),oPersonas.getUniveCiudad(),oPersonas.getUniveTitulo(),oPersonas.getUniveAno(),oPersonas.getCulturalIndigena(),oPersonas.getCulturaAfro(),oPersonas.getCulturaReinser(),oPersonas.getCulturaRoom(),oPersonas.getCulturaCabezaF(),oPersonas.getCulturaFrontera(),oPersonas.getCulturaDezpla(),oPersonas.getPagoCredito(),oPersonas.getPagoContado());

    objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInsert);
    this.mostrarDatos();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Usuario Agregado");
    if(TxtPrograma.equals("")){
       
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "jjxcasd");
    
    }
}
```

y afuera tengo este String

```
String cadena1="TÉCNICO LABORAL EN AUILIAR DE ENFERMERÍA";
```

y cuando intento comprarlo dentro del if el String no me aparece, como haría
la variable esta aqui

```
 public frmPersonas() {
    initComponents();
    this.limpiar();
    TxtFecha.setText(FechaActual());
  
    //STRING PROGRAMAS Y CURSOS
    String cadena="SELECCIONAR";
    String cadena1="TÉCNICO LABORAL EN AUILIAR DE ENFERMERÍA";
   
    String[] titulos = {"ID","Fecha","Ciudad","Programa","JorDiurna","JorNocturna","PrimerApell","SegundoApell","Nombres","FechaNaci","LugarNaci","Eps","Ars","CualAseguradora","NivelSisben","OtroSisben","CC","TI","Otro","NumeroDoc","Expedida","Masculino","Femenino","Edad","TipoSangre","Soltero","Casado","UnionL","EstadoOtro","Ocupacion","Correo","DireccionReside","Telefono","Barrio","Estrato","EntidadTraba","Cargo","FechaIngreso","DireccionEmpre","TelefonoEmpre","NombreAcu","CedulaAcu","FechaNaciAcudi","TelefonoAcu","Parentesco","ProfesionAcud","SecundariaInsti","SecundariaCiudad","SecundariaTitu","SecundariaAño","TecnicoInstitu","TecnicoCiudad","TecnicoTitulo","TecnicoAño","UniveInstitu","UniveCiudad","UniveTitu","UniveAño","CulturaIndige","CulturaAfro","CulturaReinsi","CulturaRoom","CulturaCabezaF","CulturaFronte","CulturaDezpla","PagoCredito","PagoContado"};
    model=new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);
    tblInscritos.setModel(model);
    mostrarDatos();
    
    
}
```

Comment: Donde esta definido ese string? en la misma clase? en otra clase?

Comment: lo defini afuera, en la clase principal

Comment: en si también lo que quiero es colocar un contador, pero como también re la variable afuera, no me aparece tampoco

Comment: Si la variable esta en otra clase, necesitas o traertela como parametro, o de alguna forma tener una instacia de esa clase en esta clase... al no ver todo completo, es dificil saber que necesitas exactamente...

Comment: ya coloque donde esta el STRING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la soluciones era sacar las variables de la función principal

```
int count=0;
```

y así ya se puede meter dentro de la función del botón, fue una confucion que me meti pero ya quedo.
es una bobería pero jajap listo.

Comment: honestamente, con esta respuesta entiendo menos tu problema... como esta la pregunta, es dificil entender cual fue tu problema...\

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).